# Flutter GetX Navigation: 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am very new to Dart, and coding in general. I have produced this code after watching tutorials on YouTube. For the most part, I have been able to troubleshoot most of my problems on my own, yet I cannot figure out my most recent errors. The error messages are for 'HomeScreen()',  I am unable to navigate to another screen (TodoScreen()). and they are related to positional arguments and undefined parameters. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have left the code, which I believe is necessary, down below. Thanks.

My home Page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:getxtodoyapp/controllers/todoController.dart';
import 'package:getxtodoyapp/screens/todoScreen.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // ignore: prefer_const_constructors_in_immutables
   HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
   @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final TodoController todoController = Get.put(TodoController());
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text("GetX Todo List"),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      Get.to(TodoScreen());
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
  body: Container(
    child: Obx(() => ListView.separated(
        itemBuilder: (context, i) => ListTile(
              title: Text(
                "${todoController.todos[i].text}",
                style: (todoController.todos[i].done)
                    ? const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough)
                    : const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                Get.to(TodoScreen(i));
              },
              trailing: const Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
              leading: Checkbox(
                value: todoController.todos[i].done,
                onChanged: (chandedVlaue) {
                  var changed = todoController.todos[i];
                  changed.done = chandedVlaue!;
                  todoController.todos[i] = changed;
                },
              ),
            ),
        separatorBuilder: (_, __) => Divider(),
        itemCount: todoController.todos.length)),
  ),
);
}
}
```

My Todo Screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:getxtodoyapp/controllers/todoController.dart';
import 'package:getxtodoyapp/models/todo.dart';

 class TodoScreen extends StatelessWidget {

 final TodoController todoController = Get.find();
  final int index;
 TodoScreen(this.index, {Key? key}): super(key:key);
 //TodoScreen({Key? key, this.index }) : super(key: key);
 //TodoScreen(this.index);




  @overrideWidget build(BuildContext context) {
String? text ='';
if(this.index != null){

  text = todoController.todos[index].text;

}
TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: TextField(
            controller: textEditingController,
            autofocus: true,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'What do you want to accomplish',
                border: InputBorder.none,
                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            maxLines: 999,
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {Get.back();},
              child: const Text("Cancle"),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                todoController.todos.add(Todo(text: textEditingController.text), ); 
                Get.back();

              },
              child: const Text("Add"),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
 }
 }
```

Error What I have

```
error: 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found. (not_enough_positional_arguments at [getxtodoyapp] lib\screens\homeScreen.dart:18)
info: Name source files using `lowercase_with_underscores`. (file_names at [getxtodoyapp] lib\controllers\todoController.dart:1)
info: Name source files using `lowercase_with_underscores`. (file_names at [getxtodoyapp] lib\screens\homeScreen.dart:1)
info: Prefer const with constant constructors. (prefer_const_constructors at [getxtodoyapp] lib\screens\homeScreen.dart:20)
info: Avoid unnecessary containers. (avoid_unnecessary_containers at [getxtodoyapp] lib\screens\homeScreen.dart:22)
info: Prefer const with constant constructors. (prefer_const_constructors at [getxtodoyapp] lib\screens\homeScreen.dart:46)
info: Name source files using `lowercase_with_underscores`. (file_names at [getxtodoyapp] lib\screens\todoScreen.dart:1)
info: The value of the local variable 'text' isn't used. (unused_local_variable at [getxtodoyapp] lib\screens\todoScreen.dart:18)
info: The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true. (unnecessary_null_comparison at [getxtodoyapp] lib\screens\todoScreen.dart:19)
info: Don't access members with `this` unless avoiding shadowing. (unnecessary_this at [getxtodoyapp] lib\screens\todoScreen.dart:19)
info: Prefer const with constant constructors. (prefer_const_constructors at [getxtodoyapp] lib\screens\todoScreen.dart:39)
info: Unused import: 'package:getxtodoyapp/screens/todoScreen.dart'. (unused_import at [getxtodoyapp] test\widget_test.dart:12)
```

Error When I run app

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
lib/screens/homeScreen.dart:18:28: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
      Get.to(TodoScreen());
                       ^
lib/screens/todoScreen.dart:10:1: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
 TodoScreen(this.index, {Key? key}): super(key:key);
            ^^^^^^^^^^


 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * Where:
 Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1070

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
 > Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero 
 exit value 1

 * Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

 BUILD FAILED in 13s
 Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Android Doctor

```
C:\src\projects\getxtodoyapp>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.493], locale en-IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
X cmdline-tools component is missing
  Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
  See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
X Android license status unknown.
  Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
  See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: `Get.to(TodoScreen(), arguments: [i]);`

Comment: first install "cmdline-tools;latest" from android studio sdk  setting and then in cmd  run this "flutter doctor --android-licenses" this will solve your app running interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

first of all install Android SDK command-line tools

[image: install CDK command-line tools]

then run command flutter doctor --android-licenses and press y whenever it asks for

then run `flutter clean` command then get packages in pubspec.yaml file.

to fix the issue pass the parameter in this line
[image: fix the issue]

Comment: C:\src\projects\getxtodoyapp>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.493], locale en-IN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!   Both are done. But still, the problem exists. I feel the problem is in constructive of TodoScreen.

Comment: I think the problem was With the constructor of TodoScreen. I changed it to   " TodoScreen({this.index}); "  It created new problems but I don't see this error any more

Comment: yes it will create a new problem, as now you've converted required parameter into named parameter or optional parameter, after this you have to pass the constructor with index name like TodoScreen(index: i) .

Answer (score 0):

you are using improper way.

```
final int index;
TodoScreen(this.index, {Key? key}): super(key:key);
```

**Change To**

```
final int? index;
TodoScreen( {this.index,Key? key}): super(key:key);
```

**Solved**